# multi-output regression in gpflow

Tags: gpflow

I am using gpflow for multi-output regression.

My regression target is a three-dimensional vector (correlated) and I managed to make the prediction with the full covariance matrix. Here is my implementation. More specifically, I am using SVGP after tensorflow, where f_x, Y are tensors (I am using minibatch training). During the batch training, the training examples in a minibatch are correlated, while we can assume they are independent with other examples in the training set. Hence, I would like to achieve a correlated kernel within each batch during training and the prediction with a full covariance matrix.

```
kernel = mk.SharedIndependentMok(gpflow.kernels.RBF(args.feat_dim, ARD=False, name="rbf"), args.output_dim)

# kernel = mk.SeparateIndependentMok([gpflow.kernels.RBF(128, ARD=True, name="rbf_ard"+str(i)) for i in range(3)])
q_mu = np.zeros((args.batch_size, args.output_dim)).reshape(args.batch_size * args.output_dim, 1)
q_sqrt = np.eye(args.batch_size * args.output_dim).reshape(1, args.batch_size * args.output_dim, args.batch_size * args.output_dim)
# feature = gpflow.features.InducingPoints(np.zeros((args.batch_size, 128)))

self.gp_model = gpflow.models.SVGP(X=f_X, Y=Y, kern=kernel, likelihood=gpflow.likelihoods.Gaussian(name="lik"), Z=np.zeros((args.batch_size, args.feat_dim)), q_mu=q_mu, q_sqrt=q_sqrt, name="svgp")
```

I have two questions:

1. Which kernel should I use? I read the tutorial on multi-output GP in https://gpflow.readthedocs.io/en/develop/notebooks/multioutput.html#Shared-Independent-MOK-&-Shared-Independent-Features-(SLOW-CODE), can anyone further explain the following statement? In my understanding, the kernels between different output dimensions are uncorrelated, however, we can still get the full covariance matrix in the prediction (conditional)?

> All the outputs are uncorrelated, and the same kernel is used for each
>   output. However, during the conditional calculations we do not assume
>   this particular block-diagonal structure.

2. a technical question. How should I set the "feature" when I am using gpflow after tensorflow. Should I set a numpy matix with zeros or simply as None? Seems in the batch training, the inducing point is set as the full batch as default. While how to set the feature types e.g. SharedIndependentMof, and can we set the inducing points larger than the batch size?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The notebook describes the multi-output framework and its computational aspects.  The section that you highlight just does independent GP regression, but the purpose is to show how different features, which take advantage of different block-diagonal structure, have different computational properties. It is difficult to understand exactly what you mean in a mathematical sense with training examples being corrected (correlated?) in a minibatch, and assuming that they are independent between minibatches. From the point of view of deriving the variational lower bound these are consequences rather than assumptions. However, from your description it seems that you want:

- Training with minibatches (i.e. correlations between minibatches do not need to be taken into account [Hensman et al 2013])
- A kernel that gives correlations between the outputs. Currently we only support linear correlations in `SeparateMixedMok`. A good review of the maths is by Alvarez et al.
- A feature that takes advantage of the independence properties in the prior (`MixedKernelSeparateMof`).
- Predictions with the full covariance.

This is covered by the section `3. Mixed Kernel & Uncorrelated features (OPTIMAL)`. When using the usual prediction function, just make sure to set `full_output_cov=True`.

Minibatch sizes are independent of the number of inducing points, although it's usually useless to set the number of inducing points to larger than the number of training data. Which feature to select is described above, and in the notebook. It's complicated for the multi-output case.

Note: You can also view the notebook through GitHub https://gpflow.readthedocs.io/en/master/notebooks/advanced/multioutput.html.